# Display progress bar percentage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display percentage of progress .So, I've given a span with class percentage to display it there and  id of progress bar is "progressbar". My js code is,

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
  value: 50
});

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 0
  });
  var progress = setInterval(function() {
    var currentVal = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value");
    var nextVal = currentVal + 1;
    $('#percentage').text(currentVal);
    if (nextVal > 90) {
      clearInterval(progress);
    } else {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: nextVal
      });
    }

  }, 100);
});
```

Now how can I display percentage at `#percentage`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Whats the question? Are you receiving some kind of error in the console? Or is it not displaying correctly, or not at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to show the percentage number inside the jQuery UI Progressbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896891/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-percentage-number-inside-the-jquery-ui-progressbar)

Comment: The progress bar is visible. but i dont know how to display the percentage of it So i used a span with id 'percentage'.How can i display percentage of it??

Answer (score 0):

Isn't

```
var currentVal = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
```

supposed to be

```
var currentVal = $("#progressbar").progressbar("value");
```

These should be your checkpoints

- Include jQuery.
- Include jQuery-ui after jQuery script.
- Include the    css

Comment: Thanq i corrected it but, what i want is displaying percentage